# OAuth integration with QuickBooks using Scribe

Tags: java, oauth, quickbooks, scribe, oauth-1.0a

QuickBooks has it's own SDK Libraries which can easily help to communicate between Third party. But their Library file size is around 6MB which is huge for a simple API integration.

After so much of searching and finding the solution using Scribe I decided to publish this so that other developers can use it.

intuit support are not going to help you with this and will not correct their document.

**So basically the Concern is how to integrate with Quickbooks using Scribe**

Answer (score 0):

LIBRARY : scribe-1.3.5.jar

```
public class QBOAuthDemo {
    private static String CONSUMER_KEY = "<Consumer_Key>";
    private static String CONSUMER_SECRET ="<Consumer_Secret>";
    private static String TOKEN = "<Token>";
    private static String TOKEN_SECRET = "<Token_Secret>";
    private static String API_END_URL = "https://sandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3";

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        OAuthService qbService = new ServiceBuilder()
                .provider(QuickBooksAPI.class)
                .apiKey(CONSUMER_KEY)
                .apiSecret(CONSUMER_SECRET)
                .debug()     //In order to Debug and view in Console
                .callback("http://localhost:8080")
                .build();
        Token tokenAccess = new Token(TOKEN, TOKEN_SECRET);
        System.out.println("Token Access = "+tokenAccess);

        OAuthRequest request = new OAuthRequest(Verb.GET, API_END_URL+"/company/<YOUR-COMPANYID>/customer/<customerid>");
        qbService.signRequest(tokenAccess, request);
        request.addHeader("Content-Type","application/xml" );
        Response response = request.send();
        System.out.println(response.getBody());
    }
}
```

This will simply connect and retrieve the Customer's information in the form of XML **(Also Supports JSON)**

The Response you'll be getting as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<IntuitResponse
    xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3" time="2015-06-09T06:07:39.787-07:00">
    <Customer domain="QBO" sparse="false">
        <Id>64</Id>
        <SyncToken>1</SyncToken>
        <MetaData>
            <CreateTime>2015-06-09T03:18:00-07:00</CreateTime>
            <LastUpdatedTime>2015-06-09T03:18:15-07:00</LastUpdatedTime>
        </MetaData>
        <Title>Mr</Title>
        <GivenName>DummyIND</GivenName>
        <MiddleName>B</MiddleName>
        <FamilyName>IND</FamilyName>
        <FullyQualifiedName>IND King Crafts</FullyQualifiedName>
        <CompanyName>IND King Crafts</CompanyName>
        <DisplayName>IND King Crafts</DisplayName>
        <PrintOnCheckName>IND King Crafts</PrintOnCheckName>
        <Active>true</Active>
        <PrimaryPhone>
            <FreeFormNumber>(000) 555-5555</FreeFormNumber>
        </PrimaryPhone>
        <Mobile>
            <FreeFormNumber>555-5555-6666</FreeFormNumber>
        </Mobile>
        <PrimaryEmailAddr>
            <Address>jdrew@myemail.com</Address>
        </PrimaryEmailAddr>
        <DefaultTaxCodeRef>2</DefaultTaxCodeRef>
        <Taxable>true</Taxable>
        <BillAddr>
            <Id>96</Id>
            <Line1>123 Main Street</Line1>
            <City>Mountain View</City>
            <Country>USA</Country>
            <CountrySubDivisionCode>CA</CountrySubDivisionCode>
            <PostalCode>94042</PostalCode>
            <Lat>37.37982969999999</Lat>
            <Long>-122.114632</Long>
        </BillAddr>
        <ShipAddr>
            <Id>97</Id>
            <Line1>123 Main Street</Line1>
            <City>Mountain View</City>
            <Country>IND</Country>
            <CountrySubDivisionCode>CA</CountrySubDivisionCode>
            <PostalCode>94042</PostalCode>
            <Lat>36.168973</Lat>
            <Long>-96.173524</Long>
        </ShipAddr>
        <Notes>Here are other details.</Notes>
        <Job>false</Job>
        <BillWithParent>false</BillWithParent>
        <Balance>0</Balance>
        <BalanceWithJobs>0</BalanceWithJobs>
        <CurrencyRef name="United States Dollar">USD</CurrencyRef>
        <PreferredDeliveryMethod>Print</PreferredDeliveryMethod>
    </Customer>
</IntuitResponse>
```

The class file for QuickBooksAPI.JAVA

```
import org.scribe.builder.api.DefaultApi10a;
import org.scribe.model.Token;

public class QuickBooksAPI extends DefaultApi10a{

    @Override
    public String getAccessTokenEndpoint() {
        return "https://oauth.intuit.com/oauth/v1/get_access_token";
    }

    @Override
    public String getAuthorizationUrl(Token requestToken) {
        String str = String.format("https://appcenter.intuit.com/connect/begin?oauth_token=%s",requestToken.getToken());
        return str;
    }

    @Override
    public String getRequestTokenEndpoint() {
        return "https://oauth.intuit.com/oauth/v1/get_request_token";
    }
}
```

QuickBooks support HMAC-SHA1 Signature which is automatically handled by Scribe. In order to Perform Batch Operation you can refer URL : [QUICKBOOKS BATCHOPERATION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21638115/qbov3-xml-validation-fault/21704734#21704734)